# Will a C# Class Get Instantiated Twice When Referenced from A Different Executable?

Tags: c#, singleton

I have a class `SystemConfig` on its own project and executable.

I have implemented a singleton for that class with a property called `Instance`.

So my question is, when I reference this executable in a different project and use the same singleton instance (I.e., `SystemConfig.Instance.GetConfig()`), would it be the same as the one when I run the `SystemConfig` executable?

My answer is no but just making sure.

Comment: Imagine what kind of massive security hole would be created if it was only instanciated once!

Answer (score 7):

Not only will it not be the same if you're running a different executable - it will not be the same if you run the *same* executable twice as two separate processes.

Basically, your singleton is likely to only be a singleton for a single `AppDomain`. (In most cases there's one `AppDomain` per process you start, although some apps will use more.)

Answer (score 0):

There will be one instance for each process.